# MultiBinding with Condition

Tags: wpf, binding, multibinding

I have a `TextBlock` in `WPF` and binding text property of this `TextBlock` to multi dependency property.
I want to bind these dependency property conditional. in other word I want to bind each time some dependency property to text property of `TextBlock` object. How can I do?

**Edit1 :**

My `TextBlock` is below. I calculate text property of this textblock by survey values of binding dependency properties. and want to refresh text of textblock by change each of binding dependency properties. some of binding dependency property may be null value and I don't want to binding this dependency property to my text property. When I debug my application and dependency property was null Visual studio raise warning in output window.

```
<TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource OCDFLinkTextConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="TbOCDFLink" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ocdfcontrol:OCDFLink}"/>
                    <Binding Path="TbOCDFLink.FromOCDFObjectItem.OCDFObject.XPosition" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ocdfcontrol:OCDFLink}"/>
                    <Binding Path="TbOCDFLink.FromOCDFObjectItem.OCDFObject.YPosition" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ocdfcontrol:OCDFLink}"/>
                    <Binding Path="TbOCDFLink.ToOCDFObjectItem.OCDFObject.XPosition" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ocdfcontrol:OCDFLink}"/>
                    <Binding Path="TbOCDFLink.ToOCDFObjectItem.OCDFObject.YPosition" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ocdfcontrol:OCDFLink}"/>
                    <Binding Path="TbOCDFLink.FromOCDFObjectItem.OCDFObject.ParentOCDFObject.XPosition" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ocdfcontrol:OCDFLink}"/>
                    <Binding Path="TbOCDFLink.FromOCDFObjectItem.OCDFObject.ParentOCDFObject.YPosition" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ocdfcontrol:OCDFLink}"/>
                    <Binding Path="TbOCDFLink.ToOCDFObjectItem.OCDFObject.ParentOCDFObject.XPosition" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ocdfcontrol:OCDFLink}"/>
                    <Binding Path="TbOCDFLink.ToOCDFObjectItem.OCDFObject.ParentOCDFObject.YPosition" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ocdfcontrol:OCDFLink}"/>
                    <Binding Path="TbOCDFLink.TbOCDFLinkGroup.FromOCDFObjectItem" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ocdfcontrol:OCDFLink}"/>
                    <Binding Path="TbOCDFLink.TbOCDFLinkGroup.ToOCDFObjectItem" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ocdfcontrol:OCDFLink}"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
```

Comment: can you please elaborate what kind of multidependency property you want to bind the Text property of TextBlock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try this in your converter

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
 {
     string result="";
     if (values != null)
     {
         foreach (var val in values)
         {
             if (val == null)
                 continue;
             else
                 result = result + val;

         }
     }
     return result;
 }
```

I Expect your all binding is working.I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks. but when you look at the output window of visual studio see warning about binding null value to text property.

Comment: obviously it will show null because they really are null , If you dont want that then just specify TargetNullValue in Binding.

Comment: thank you very much. I must use `TargetNullValue` in Binding.